# How to create new columns deriving from a categorical column in python?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with a categorical column(TweetType) with three categories (T, RT and RE). I want to count how many times these categories appear and then sum them. I created three new columns, respectively T, RT, and RE.

```
def tweet_type(df):
    result = df.copy()
    result['T'] = result['tweetType'].str.contains("T")
    result['RT'] = resulT['tweetType'].str.contains("RT")
    result['RE'] = result['tweetType'].str.contains("RE")
    return result
tweet_type(my_df)
```

Then I converted the boolean into 0 and 1. The problem is that the code matches T as RT and the result is not right.

What I obtain is:

```
TweetType RT  T  RE

RT        1   1   0

RE        0   0   1

T         1   0   0

RT        1   1   0
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `str.contains` you should use boolean `eq` for exact matches:

```
def tweet_type(df):
    result = df.copy()
    result['T'] = result['Tweet_Type'].eq("T")
    result['RT'] = result['Tweet_Type'].eq("RT")
    result['RE'] = result['Tweet_Type'].eq("RE")
    return result
```

However, there is an easier method for what you're trying to achieve.
Why not use `one-hot encoding` using [get_dummies](https://pandas.pydata.org/docs/reference/api/pandas.get_dummies.html) to do this:

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["Tweet_Type"])
```

If you don't want the prefix `Tweet_Type_`:

```
new_df = pd.get_dummies(df, columns=["Tweet_Type"], prefix='', prefix_sep='')
```

If you wish to retain the first column:

```
df = pd.concat([df, new_df], axis=1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use logical `and` to exclude the records that contain `RT`

```py
(result['tweetType'].str.contains("T")) & (~result['tweetType'].str.contains("RT"))
```